# Java - How to call method class with interface without know class name

Tags: java, interface

I'm new in java, I want to call method class from implemented Class with interface without know class name "ClassA", which only know Object c and I have 2 file.

File (1) CobaInterface.java

```
package cobainterface;

public class CobaInterface {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ImplementedClass implementedClass = new ImplementedClass();

        ClassA clsA = new ClassA();
        implementedClass.myMethodFromClassA(clsA);
    }

}

class ClassA{
    public Integer getTwo(){
        return 2;
    }
}

interface MyInterface {
    public void myMethod();

    //here interface
    public void myMethodFromClassA(Object c);
}
```

File (2) : ImpementedClass.java

```
package cobainterface;

public class ImplementedClass extends CobaInterface {
    public void myMethodFromClassA(Object c) {
        //System.out.println(c.getTwo()); <- wrong when call method c.getTwo()
    }
}
```

How about if I want to call method getTwo() from ClassA without know Class Name, which only know Object c from file (2) as describe in code above. Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use generic types so the implementation knows what the object will be,

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
    public void myMethod();

    //here interface
    public void myMethodFromClassA(T c);
}
```

The impl becomes,

```
package cobainterface;

public class ImplementedClass Implements MyInterface<ClassA> {
    public void myMethodFromClassA(ClassA c) {
        //System.out.println(c.getTwo()); <- wrong when call method c.getTwo()
    }
}
```

All together,

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ImplementedClass implementedClass = new ImplementedClass();

        ClassA clsA = new ClassA();
        implementedClass.myMethodFromClassA(clsA);
    }

}

class ImplementedClass implements MyInterface<ClassA> {
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {

    }

    @Override
    public void myMethodFromClassA(ClassA c) {
        System.out.println(c.getTwo());
    }
}

class ClassA {
    public Integer getTwo() {
        return 2;
    }
}

interface MyInterface<T> {
    void myMethod();

    void myMethodFromClassA(T c);
}
```

You could also do a cast

```
System.out.println((MyClass)c.getTwo());
```

but you will lose all benefit of type saftey.

Comment: *You could also do a cast* - maybe should check with `instanceof`

Comment: completely slipped my mind, there's a few ways to be safer with casting. @ScaryWombat. mentions.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Thanks for help,, that's opened my mind about java,,